# Kinvey-Xamarin: How to recieve Data from a User instance?

Tags: xamarin, kinvey

I'm working on a Kinvey project right now, and I'm having some Problems with reading the Username or special Attributes from a User instance. I first tried it the same way getting `_User.ID` by calling `_User.UserName`, but this didnt return anything(But ID did curiously). I also searched on Google, but there weren't any articles about it. Hope you can help, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For special attributes, use the `.Attributes` array on the `User` class.
Like this code:

```
Console.WriteLine ("custom attribute is: " + kinveyClient.User ().Attributes["myAttribute"]);
```

For username, try `.UserName()` but it seems you must do an explicit retrieval of the User object before this field is populated

```
User retrieved;
try {
    retrieved = await kinveyClient.User().RetrieveAsync();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} caught exception: ", e);
    retrieved = null;
}
Console.WriteLine ("logged in as: " + retrieved.Username );
Console.WriteLine ("custom attribute is: " + retrieved.Attributes["myAttribute"]);
```

Documentation: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/xamarin/guides/users#UserClass

(answer applies to SDK version 1.6.11)